# Angular 12 - two way data binding & triggers

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, eventtrigger, 2-way-object-databinding

This is more of a question of is it possible then I have an error.
This is the situation that I am currently in:

1. I have an item on the 'grid' system. 
    [image: grid]
2. The item can be spaned on multiple rows and columns while the save button is there, present after the position is locked in place. The save button cannot be reused after it has been clicked.
3. Idea was to have two changeable values on the dialog that would be used for changing the current span of the field. 
    [image: properties]
4. I've implemented that (I have two input fields that save data into them and to the corresponding element in the grid) but I cannot wrap my brain around how to 'trigger' changing of span after closing the dialog. 
   I have one component as a component of the grid component (the Text Box component) that has a child dialog component in it. So when closing the dialog occurs it 'ends' on Text Box component and not in the grid component where I should actually change the span.

    
   Is there a way to trigger something on the grid ([grand]parent component) for a change on the child component (afterClose() event on Text Box component)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could try is to pass the updated item including the new colX and colY values by `dialog.afterClose().subscribe(result ...)` and then pass the updated item down to your TextBoxComponent.

Check the last example on:
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples.

Check out the OnChanges interface which also might by helpful if you want to react on attribute changes: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

**But**
I guess the preferred way here would be to feed your text boxes with items from a store like @ngrx/store and communicate with your item collection via action stream. Dispatch an UpdateItemAction from your modal and the whole grid always adapts to your current collection state.

Something like

```
<box-grid>
   <text-box [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of items$ | async"></text-box>
</box-grid>
```

Furthermore i would not recommend to generate modals for every textbox. Just open one modal(lazy loaded) and pass the item entity to the data attribute:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'edit-item-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.item.colX }}',
})
export class EditItemDialog {
  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { item: Item }
   ) { }

  // Dispatch your update action here and close the modal
  updateItem(item: Item): void {
    this.store.dispatch(updateItem( { item } ));
    // close dialog

  }
}
```

Hope this helps and i got your issue correct.